# Aggregating data from 3 tables in PostgreSQL and creating array of objects as result

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I have 3 tables like so:

**companies**

```
   id  |settings (jsonb data type)            | address
  -----|--------------------------------------|--------
   5   |{name: 'Company Blue', severity': 1}  | 1st St
   9   |{name: 'Company Red', severity': 7}   | 2nd St
   21  |{name: 'Company Yellow', severity': 4}| 2nd St
   37  |{name: 'Company Pink', severity': 4}  | 2nd St
   199 |{name: 'Company Red', severity': 2}   | 2nd St
```

**orders**

```
id  | items                   | Shipping provider | amount
----|-------------------------|-------------------|-------
17  | ['apple', 'samsung']    |'Lab Inc'          | $1238
23  | ['sony', 'apple', 'ibm']|'Crew Ltd'         | $490
```

**orders_companies**

```
id  | order | company 
----|-------|---------
 2  | 17    | 5       
 3  | 17    | 37      
 4  | 17    | 21      
 5  | 23    | 199     
 6  | 23    | 5
```

As we can see here: one order relates to multiple companies.
I would like to query **orders** table to get the following **result**:

| id | items | Shipping provider | amount | companies |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17 | ['apple', 'samsung'] | 'Lab Inc' | $1238 | [{name: 'Company Blue', id: 5}, {name: 'Company Yellow', id: 21}, {name: 'Company Pink', id: 37 } ] |
| 23 | ['sony', 'apple', 'ibm'] | 'Crew Ltd' | $490 | [{name: 'Company Blue', id: 5}, {name: 'Company Red', id: 199}] |

I am stacked because of jsonb settings column - I had an error of missing WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `json_build_object` to build the company object and then `json_agg` group those company objects into one array of objects :

```
with cte as (
  select o.id, o.items, o.shipping_provider, o.amount, c.id as company_id, settings->>'name' as company_name
  from orders o
  inner join orders_companies oc on oc.order_ = o.id
  inner join companies c on c.id = oc.company
)
select id, items, shipping_provider, amount, 
          COALESCE(
              json_agg(
                  json_build_object(
                      'name', company_name,
                      'id', company_id
                  ) 
              ) FILTER (WHERE company_id IS NOT NULL), '[]'
         )
from cte
group by id, items, shipping_provider, amount
order by id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/XUFzmF_L)